# How to add an array of data to a DF from another based on ID?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have DF1:

```
ID   Name

12   Bob

13   John
```

And DF2:

```
ID   Hr   Str

12   22   33

12   24   34

13   12   22
```

OutPut:
DF3:

```
ID  NAME  Hr       Str

12  Bob   [22,24]  [33,34]

13  John  [12]     [22]
```

Comment: What is the different compare with your previous question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520126/trying-to-join-2-dataframes-and-store-certain-data-as-an-array-in-one-cell/52520296#52520296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), but you lose the vectorised functionality which goes with using NumPy arrays held in contiguous memory blocks:

```
df = df1.join(df2.groupby('ID').agg(list), on='ID')
#old pandas version alternative
#df = df1.join(df2.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: x.tolist()), on='ID')
print (df)
   ID  Name        Hr       Str
0  12   Bob  [22, 24]  [33, 34]
1  13  John      [12]      [22]
```

Comment: Is there a way to only keep unique values in the arrays without using a set?  I want it to be an array with unique values.

Comment: @JSnoob - Sure, use `df = df1.join(df2.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()), on='ID')`